# Windows interface rendering not working properly in Fedora

Tags: fedora, xfce, theme, window

I've got little problem with windows interface style rendering. Please see picture beneath. I've tried to reinstall all gtk* packages, but it didn't helped.
Im running up to date Fedora with XFCE 4.12 de on latest stable kernel. This is not happening in all gui apps.

[image: Picture describing the problem]

If I run filezilla from terminal it outputs errorrs like

```
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:31:10: The 'engine' property is ignored
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:33:23: Custom CSS properties are no longer supported.
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:34:22: Custom CSS properties are no longer supported.
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:51:39: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:52:39: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:53:39: The style property GtkWidget:interior-focus is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:13: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:99:17: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:99:37: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:125:36: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
(filezilla:22233): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:149:23: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
```

Please could you guide me where to search? I haven't find anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing theme to newer version.